# React Native: Open link on image click

Tags: react-native

I have an array `arr` of dictionary whose elements go like:

```
{url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/', picUrl: 'link to pic', ...}
```

I want to open the `i-th` link when the `i-th` image is clicked. My code goes as:

```
arr = this.example[key];
var arrayLength = arr.length;
for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
  console.log(arr[i].url);
  var x = arr[i].url;
  views.push(
    <View>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{uri: arr[i].picUrl}}
        style={{ width: '100%',aspectRatio: 1, height: undefined }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => Linking.openURL(x)}
// or     onPress={() => Linking.openURL(arr[i].url)}
          style={{flex: 1}}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ImageBackground>
      .....
```

When I click the image, I get this error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'arr[i].url')
```

I then verified that arr[i] etc. aren't undefined by:

```
console.log(arr[i])
console.log(arr[i].url)
```

and got correct values (`'https://stackoverflow.com/'` for this example).

When I hardcode the value to `'https://stackoverflow.com/'`, everything seems to work fine, which means there is an issue with the line `Linking.openURL(arr[i].url)` only. What exactly? I don't know :(

I've been stuck at this issue for quite some time, saw a few posts related to this, but nothing help. Can someone help me resolve this issue? Thanks...

---

**Update:**

I changed `onPress={() => Linking.openURL(arr[i].url)}` to:

```
onPress={() => Alert.alert(arr[i])}
```

and I got a completely blank alert!

Then, I did:

```
var x = arr[i].url
```

and changed the earlier line to:

```
onPress={() => Linking.openURL(x)}
```

Now, for all of the images, the link is set to `arr[length-1].url`, that is, its equal to the value of the url of the very last image in the array!

Comment: Hi Ankit, check my solution and let me know if that helps. BTW, can you show, how you are iterating aver the array? Why you are using `arr[i]`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 done

Comment: What is `this.example[key]`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 It's a dictionary. Contains data I am receiving using axios. Corresponding to each key, I have an array of dictionaries (`arr`) as its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first check if app can handle this URL using [`canOpenURL`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#canopenurl)

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => Linking.canOpenURL(arr[i].url)
                     .then((supported) => {
                       if (!supported) {
                         console.log("Can't handle url: " + arr[i].url);
                       } else {
                         return Linking.openURL(arr[i].url);
                       }
                     })
                     .catch((err) => console.error('An error occurred', err));
    }
    style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ImageBackground
         source={{uri: arr[i].picUrl}}
         style={{ width: '100%',aspectRatio: 1, height: undefined }}>
      </ImageBackground>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

---

**Update**

Instead of for loop you can use `map`,

```
let views = arr.map(data => <View>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{uri: data.picUrl}}
        style={{ width: '100%',aspectRatio: 1, height: undefined }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => Linking.openURL(data.url)}
          style={{flex: 1}}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ImageBackground>
</View>
)
```

Comment: I'll check this in a minute

Comment: Still getting the exact same error (on line `Linking.canOpenURL(arr[i].url)`)

Comment: I think you need to wrap your `ImageBackground` with `TouchableOpacity`, check the updated answer.

Comment: That's not the issue. It's working fine when I harcode the url

Comment: @AnkitKumar, instead of `var` in for loop try to use `let`.

Comment: Can you please compile the comments and edit your answer? Will accept the answer than :)

Comment: @AnkitKumar, Try with `map` and let me know if that also helps.

Comment: I have some restrictions in my implementation and hence can't use map. It will work anyway, I used map before switching to for loop (need index!)